# React аутентификация не работает route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Имеется React приложение с аутентификацией, логин / регистрация работают успешно, но сама форма регистрации или логина почему-то открывается на той же самой странице, где и есть эти кнопки логина и пароля, прямо под ними появляется форма, а мне хотелось бы, чтобы сама форма появлялась на новой странице, я настроил роут, все указал, но почему-то ничего не работает, я новичок, поэтому буду рад любой помощи, спасибо большое, есть мнение, что дело в рендере страница, поэтому так же добавлю index.js, вот код роутов :

```
function App() {
    const isAuth = useSelector(state => state.user.isAuth)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(auth())
    }, [])


    return (
        <>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
                <Navbar />
                    {!isAuth &&
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/registration" component={Registration}/>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    </Switch>
                    }
                    <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}
```

```
return (
        <>
        <MainPage>
                <Btn1>{!isAuth && <Button className="btn1"><Link href="/login"><Text>Sign In</Text></Link></Button> }</Btn1>
                <Btn2>{!isAuth && <Button className="btn2"><Link href="/registration"><Text>Sign Up</Text></Link></Button> }</Btn2>
                {isAuth && <Button onClick={() => dispatch(logout()) }><Text>Sign Out</Text></Button> }
        </MainPage>
        </>
    );
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

зачем тебе добавочный Btn1 вокруг Button странно

```
<Btn1>{!isAuth && <Button className="btn1"><Link href="/login"><Text>Sign In</Text></Link></Button> }</Btn1>
```

проблема наверное в `<Link href="/login">` его синтексис такой `<Link to="/today"/>` проверь если все норм дай знать

Comment: спасибо, все норм! а Btn1 - для стилизации)

Comment: @Anfieldy не за что рад помочь)